# Is there an inherent problem with expanding chainring drives such as Veridrive and WaveTrans?

Tags: chainring

The Veridrive is just the latest iteration of the idea of using an expanding or contracting chainring rather than a derailleur for shifting:

There also WaveTrans:

We've seen this design tried before (Linley & Biggs' Protean Gear in 1896). What are the problems with these types of systems that make their mass implementation doubtful? On the surface, they seem simpler than epicyclical (planetary) gear systems such as internal geared hubs and cranks.

Comment: The inherent problem with WaveTrans is that, you don't have it.

Comment: At a guess it will be something to do with added complexity and moving parts in an area subject to high torque.  Weight is a likely follow-on from those.

Comment: Possibly they also offer a lower range of ratios than what is possible modern 2x11 or even 1x11 derailleur setup.

Comment: Observe that the "ring" will not be perfectly circular, and as a result the pedals will be felt to "thump" as you crank them.

Comment: @DanielRHicks they'll probably market it as a feature *à la* biopace (hopefully adjusting the shape so they thump a little at all speed rather than a lot at some).  Or get it badly wrong and use an odd number of sections so it's assymetric.

Comment: [This picture](http://www.veterancycleclublibrary.org.uk/ncl/pics/new_protean_gear_vcc_library.jpg) of the Protean suggests it's an early derailleur with shift ramps rather than a variable system

Comment: @ChrisH -- The Veridrive appears to have 5 segments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One possible problem with the Wavetrans is that that a chain drive is inherently *not* CVT. It is based on integer ratios of teeth. If a given blade of the front ring is aligned and meshing with the chain, its neighbor is likely not aligned properly except in certain precise diameters:

```
(o = o)=(o = o)=(o = o)=(o = o)=(o = o)=(o = o)=(o = o)=(o = o)=(o = o)  [chain]
   ^   ^   ^   ^   ^                            ^   ^   ^   ^   ^        [chainring]
      aligned          <== variable gap =>       oops, not quite
```

It's okay when the arrangement is precisely simulating a 48T ring or a 49T ring; but what if it's sitting at the effective equivalent of "48.37T"? Oops; there is no such thing; it's a  misaligned case with "phase shifts" between the sections of the ring, that are fractions of the 0.5" link spacing which the chain doesn't conform to.

This could cause issues.

Aha, "it's controlled by a microprocessor and a PLC" and actually has six speeds. This probably means what it sounds like it means: the microprocessor dials in proper non-fractional-T ring sizes.

If this control system is open-loop (has no error feedback telling it whether it has actually achieved an integer ring size), it's doomed to drift.

A microprocessor can be generally regarded as just another problem, not a solution.

Comment: The segmented chainring doesn't have to be round. The only thing that matters for gear ratio is the distance from chain contact point to center of rotation. The load is carried by a few teeth closest to contact, the rest could just flex to match with chain links. Actually, you could get rid of the tensioner this way.

Comment: This is right but the figure confused me at first.  I've suggested an edit -- feel free to roll back if I've made it worse.

Comment: @ojs Yes, the segmented chain ring doesn't have to be round and I didn't say that. I effectively said it has to contain an integral number of teeth. For instance, the ovoid/elliptical rings have that property.

Comment: The last sentence alone would deserve a +1

Comment: @ojs I thought of the flex, but it could only flex in one direction; it had better be rigid under drive load! The error in the teeth could be either way. Then again, it doesn't have to flex in the direction of least error.

Comment: @Kaz I if you think how oval chainrings work, you'll see why how you can have continuously variable transmission with discrete chain links and non-round cogs.

Comment: @ojs, but here we have discreet regions in which there is the potential for non-integer spacing.  In oval chainrings there's a (small) change in gear ratio within a revolution, which is a different case.

Comment: @ojs Oval chainrings only vary the torque over a duty cycle (revolution of pedals) relative to a circular ring. They do not achieve a continuously variable gear ratio. The number of revolutions of the crank to the number of revolutions of the cassette is a ratio of integers, determined by the tooth count.

Comment: Shifting would be horrible under load if the gear has to jump from one size to another in some integer effective-tooth-count step.  Unless you have one actuator per segment and shift unloaded segements; that would massively increase the chances of failure.

Comment: Picture of what I thought: http://ojs.kapsi.fi/chaincontact.png. Yes, that would be moving unloaded segments. As far as I can tell, you'd need only to design the segments so that they have fixed position when loaded, otherwise they could be just spring loaded. Yes, this is ridiculously complex but so is WaveTrans anyway.

Comment: For a component that is flexible in one direction and rigid in other, check how freewheels work.

Comment: @ojs sprung outwards and restricted in how they move inwards might work.  The spring travel would have to be just right: too small and it would be useless; too big and the ring could mess with the wrong tooth.  This might have to scale with diameter as well.

Comment: I agree with ojs - as long as the parts actually in contact with the chain have integral spacing the rest is largely unconstrained. If you're willing to have enough mechanical complexity the "footwheels" from fiction by Bruce Sterling and Terry Pratchett could also have spikes added and be used as chainrings (using nanotech and magic respectively). Just aloowing a little slop in the critical direction could be enough to allow this to work, and make fractional chainring sizes (and ramped/oval virtual chainrings simple). Otherwise how does the thing change size in the first place?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, there are problems.

Not only do the mechanisms have to be complex, as you can see in the videos, but they have to be **very strong**, too. The moving parts of the chainring drive has to withstand the total force the rider is delivering, because the input to the pedals will try to drive the expanding elements inwards. Complicated precision mechanisms, high strength, and low weight is a combination that is rarely found together for reasonable prices.

Compare that to a derailleur system. In a derailleur based drivetrain, the derailleur doesn't see any significant loads. All it really has to do is to move the chain from side to side. That's about it. It can be a little tricky when you are shifting under load, but pins and ramps on chainrings and cogs can do the job to ease the load on the derailleur.

In the expanding chainrings, that has to bear the brunt of the entire rider's power output.

Ever had a brake cable slip through the binding bolt while braking? That was only with hand power. Imagine standing on the brake lever, imagine how much of a hassle it would be to make that connection rigid enough. Furthermore, imagine trying to shift under load when you have to overcome the force you're putting to the pedals.

You still need a chain tensioner on the drivetrain too with these systems so there really isn't any benefit apart from novelty.

Comment: Some numbers: With a reasonable but low weight limit each pedal might be expected to have 1kN (the force of 100kg pressing on it) once or twice a second; 50N is more typical for hand grip strength.  Also you brake much less often than you pedal, so if there's any creep in a braking system that's a periodic adjustment, in a system subject to drive forces it would be every few minutes.  Assuming (unrealistically) similar hardware.

Comment: Because the distance between links is fixed, its impossible to change the diameter of the portion of the chainring that's under tension. I assume the system would change the diameter of the sections when they are unloadd or free of the chain (i.e., oriented to the rear of the bicycle). Thus, you'd never have to pit hand strength against leg strength.

Answer (score 0):

I attempted to make a CVT like this. However in the end it turned out to be impractical. Here is what I came up with:

Comment: Can you [edit] some words in to say why it was impractical?  Your video is very nice but I can't see what the issues were.

Comment: To me it looks like a planetary gear without any capability for shifting. That is sure impractical as CVT.